# Calender locale translations not support for Jasper server 8.*.* versions

Tags: jasperserver

I moved from 7.8.0 jasper server version to 8.2.0 version. but, calendar translations not changing as usual when create new calendar.properties files according to locale. but 7.8.0 version support that locale translations. I mean calender date picker popup (on inputControls section when we add Date type input control as a parameter from jasper server) translations according to selected localization on the jasper login page.

for default jasper server aready existing locales either not change calender translations. it is always English.

I checked with all jasper server 8 sub versions and non of them worked.

Is this a bug? or is there any solution? please help me.[image]